# android regex not find the matcher

Tags: java, android, regex

i am ussing a regex in android to read an user input which is something like this :
1:10&3:20
d20
3:10

(just to know, i send this input to an arduino)

i need to verify if the user breaks the line and if does, i send the line to the arduino. If the line begins with a 'd'(like the second one), it will set a delay and the time will be the next integers in the line;

here is what i code, but the problem is when i try to verify if the matcher finds what i set in the compile

```
final String expression = aux.getCodigo().toString();
                    //System.out.println("mandeii " + MenuActivity.mIn.read());

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(\n)'");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
                    System.out.println("achei ");
                    if (matcher.find()){
                        System.out.println("found the first endLine"+ matcher);
                        if (matcher.group(0).charAt(0) == 'd') {
                            System.out.println("achei o d "+matcher.group(0).charAt(0));
                            int v1 = matcher.group(0).charAt(1);
                            if (matcher.group(0).charAt(2) != '\n') {
                                int v2 = matcher.group(0).charAt(2);
                                int valor = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(v1) + String.valueOf(v2));
                                System.out.println("valor "+valor);
                                new CountDownTimer(valor * 1000, 1000) {
                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        System.out.println("delayed");
                                    }

                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
                                    }
                                }.start();

                            } else {
                                new CountDownTimer(v1 * 1000, 1000) {
                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        System.out.println("delayed");
                                    }

                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
                                    }
                                }.start();

                            }

                        }
                        else MenuActivity.mOut.write(matcher.group(0).getBytes());
```

if someone knows, it would help me a lot,
tks

Comment: If you want to split line by carriage return `\n` you can use `String.split(System.lineSeparator())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you just need to split the line into chunks (pieces), using \n as chunk separator. Right? Then why to make it so complex, since there is a nice *split* method:

```
  // This must run in a NON-UI thread!
   //===================================== 
   try {
     for (String chunk: expression.split("\n")) {
        if (chunk.charAt(0) == 'd') {
            int valor; 
            if (chunk.length() > 1 &&
                (valor = Integer.parseInt(chunk.substring(1)))> 0) {
                    System.out.println("Delay " + valor + " millisec");
                    Thread.sleep(valor);
             }
        } else 
            MenuActivity.mOut.write(chunk.getBytes());

      } // End of for loop
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
         System.out.println("Cancelled");
    }

   }
```

Comment: This is completely right cyanide, tks so much for the help. i forgot that i could use the currently thread ...tks :)